# how to use $document in angularjs to add the inline css?

Tags: angularjs

I want to add one width property to my text by selecting the class name.

```
$('input.select2-input').css('width', '330px');
```

Pure angularjs way to do this. Thanks

Comment: jQlite(built in light version of jQ in angular) doesn't have out of box support for selectors....  so you either use jQ or vanilla js..

Comment: The angular way is not to do it that way at all. Instead make sure that the relevant elements have an `ng-style` or `ng-class` attribute that references some value from the model and update the model when you want to change the style/class.

Comment: @Duncan well said Duncan... well said..

Answer (score 4):

to have Angular-way of doing things **use ng-class instead**.

Answer (score 1):

### 3 solutions :

---

### 1. Using [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) :

**- HTML :**

```
<div ng-style="{ 'width' : width }"></div>
```

**- In your controller :**

```
$scope.width = "330px";
```

---

### 2. Using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) :

**- HTML :**

```
<div ng-class="{myStyle : myExpression}"></div>
```

**- CSS :**

```
.myStyle {
    width : 330px;
}
```

**- In your controller :**

```
$scope.myExpression = true;
```

---

### 3. Using [JQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) :

Angular itself provide JQlite for basic Jquery needs, but for having your code clear, logic, editable **this way is really not recommended** :

```
var element = angular.element( document.querySelector('input.select2-input') );
element.css('width', '330px');
```

Answer (score 0):

In manipulating the DOM use a directive, in the link function. You can inject `$document` or just get the element in the link function then add css styles.